# Access asp content from a Popup Window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access a asp TreeView from a Popup window. I made it public, so I can have access.
Code in Chile or Popup Page,

```
SomeWebPage FlViewPage = new SomeWebPage(); 
lblMessage.Text = FlViewPage.TreeView1.Nodes.Count.ToString();
```

The problem is that when I run the WebSite I got an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

WebPage (From which the Popup is called) Code the Tree is populated dynamically,

```
    <%@ Page Title="Folder View" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FolderView.aspx.cs" Inherits="SwimWebFile.FolderView" %>
<div id="content"> <div class="post">
<h1 class="title"> <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Documents"></asp:Label></h1>
    <div class="entry" >
     <!-- Center the pop window in the middle -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
                var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
                var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
                var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            } 
        </script>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PopupCenter('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Document',340,185);">Click Here for Upload</a>
        <font size="4">
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewDocuments" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" 
            ImageSet="Simple" Visible="False" onprerender="TreeView_PreRender">
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
            <LeafNodeStyle NodeSpacing="10px" />
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="System" Value="Systems" Expanded="False" 
                    SelectAction="Expand">
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Document" Value="Documents" Expanded="False" 
                    SelectAction="Expand">
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" 
                HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="7px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" 
                HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
        </asp:TreeView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNewFolder" runat="server" Text="New Folder" 
            onclick="btnNewFolder_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRenameFolder" runat="server" Text="Rename Folder" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteFolder" runat="server" Text="Delete Folder" />
   </font></div>
</div>
```

Code behind,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                TreeViewDocuments.Visible = false;
                lblTitle.Text = "You need to be logged in.";
            }
            else
                TreeViewDocuments.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void TreeView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           AddNewNode();
        }
    }
    // Some Code to pop 
     protected void AddNewNode()
     {
      ...
     }
    .
    .
    .
    protected void btnNewFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "targetWin = window.open('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Folder', 'toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, resizable= 0, menubar=0, copyhistory=no, width=460, height=150');  targetWin.moveTo((screen.height / 2) - (150/ 2), (screen.width / 2) - (460 / 2));", true);
    }
```

Error,

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

Line 56:             FolderView FlViewPage = new FolderView();
Line 57:             lblMessage.Text = FlViewPage.TreeViewDocuments.Nodes.Count.ToString();

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   SwimWebFile.NewFolderPopup.btnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\...\NewFolderPopup.aspx.cs:57
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot that could be null I would hook up a debugger to it and see what is null. At this point my guess is Treeview1 or FlViewPage is but I might not have the full picture as well

Comment: Yeah is confusing because, the TreeView is already populated in SomeWebPage, so I don't know why is no passing it parameters or nodes.

Comment: Can you post what somewebpage looks Luke ?

Comment: Code added. The Popup window is opened when the btnNewFolder is called from the FolderView.aspx. I want to get the TreeView nodes to this popup window.

Comment: Can you post the call stack that your getting with the exception ?

Comment: Stack trace added. I just put the '.count' to see if some value can be transfer between the web pages.

Comment: what is on line 58 ? 
NewFolderPopup.aspx.cs:58

Comment: Well sorry, the line should be 57, the problem is that I was editing to remove unnecessary comments or blank spaces.

Comment: ok what I would do is set the label to  FlViewPage.tostring() if that works do  FlViewPage.TreeView1.tostring ect and figure out where your issue is

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this problem. I used the [Session](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12303/Passing-Values-from-Child-Page-to-Parent-Page) method to receive just the value instead the whole TreeView.

Thanks for the advice!